# Deploying opencv python on zeit returns build error

Tags: python, docker

Hi my requirements file for docker is this.

my dockerfile

```
FROM python:3-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
ENV GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS="--bind=0.0.0.0"
CMD ["gunicorn", "myapp:app"]
```

my requirements txt

```
Flask==1.0.2
gunicorn==19.9.0
opencv-python==3.4.3
numpy==1.15.2
```

without last two lines build is success